# Flutter Switch with shared preference not working the first change

Tags: flutter, switch-statement, sharedpreferences, persistence

I need the information of the switch value (true or false) in antoher file to calculate something.
When the Switch is on false and I restart the app the Switch is still on false and if I click it, the value will go to true and the calculation is performed with it.

Now my problem:
If I have the switch on true and close the app and restarted, the value will stay true (which is nice) but if I click now the Switch the value should go to false in the second file but it does not and hence the calculation is not using this false. After click on the Switch 2 more times it works perfectly.

Do you have any ideas how and what to change? I would be very thankful!

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:ncrechner/Allgemein/state_widget.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DienstState createState() => DienstState();
}

@override
class DienstState extends State<Test> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DienstSwitch();
  }
}

class SwitchHelper with ChangeNotifier{
bool _switchValue;
final SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();


updataValue() async{
_switchValue = await prefs.getBool("isSwitchedDienst1");
_switchValue = !_switchValue;
prefs.setBool("isSwitchedDienst1", _switchValue);
notifyListeners();

}
}
class DienstSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DienstSwitchState createState() => new DienstSwitchState();
}

bool isSwitchedDienst1 = false;

class DienstSwitchState extends State<DienstSwitch> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadisSwitchedDienst();
  }

  loadisSwitchedDienst() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isSwitchedDienst1 =
        (prefs.getBool("isSwitchedDienst1") ?? isSwitchedDienst1);
  }

  incrementisSwitchedDienst() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isSwitchedDienst1 =
          (prefs.getBool('isSwitchedDienst1') ?? isSwitchedDienst1);
      prefs.setBool(("isSwitchedDienst1"), isSwitchedDienst1);
    });
  }

  removeisSwitchedDienst() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove('isSwitchedDienst1');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoSwitch(
      value: isSwitchedDienst1,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        Provider.of<SwitchHelper>(context).updataValue();
        //removeisSwitchedDienst();
        //incrementisSwitchedDienst();
        /*setState(
          () {
            isSwitchedDienst1 = value;
            //final provider = StateInheritedWidget.of(context);
            //provider.changeSwitchDienst(isSwitchedDienst1);
          },
        );*/
      },
      activeColor: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```

and my main looks like :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:ncrechner/DreamOn/Angaben/test.dart';
import 'package:ncrechner/nav.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'Allgemein/state_widget.dart';
import 'onboarding.dart';

int initScreen;
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  initScreen = prefs.getInt("initScreen");
  await prefs.setInt("initScreen", 1);
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ],
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}

/*class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StateWidget(
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return
*/
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SwitchHelper())],
      child: MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: initScreen == 0 || initScreen == null ? "first" : "/",
        routes: {
          "/": (context) => Navigation(),
          "first": (context) => OnBoardingPage(),
        },
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(150),
          accentColor: Colors.blue,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              onPrimary: Colors.black,
              primary: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          toggleButtonsTheme: ToggleButtonsThemeData(
              color: Colors.black,
              selectedColor: Colors.black,
              fillColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4)),
        ),
        darkTheme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          primaryColor: Colors.grey[900],
          buttonColor: Colors.grey[900],
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
          accentColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
        /* ThemeMode.system to follow system theme, 
               ThemeMode.light for light theme, 
               ThemeMode.dark for dark theme
              */
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the setState() is not working as per your instruction. I am also new with flutter. but I think If you use provider it will solve your issue.

In this order you need to create a new class.

```
class SwitchHelper with ChangeNotifier{
bool_switchValue;
final SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();


updataValue() async{
_switchValue = await prefs.getBool("isSwitchedDienst1");
_switchValue = !_switchValue;
prefs.setBool("isSwitchedDienst1", _switchValue);
notifyListeners();

}
}
```

so basically what this does it will get the value from the `SharedPrefernces` and then store it in variable. The method `updateValue` will be called on tap of switch or your button. once the method is called it will change the value of the `bool` variable  and set it's value to the sharedPreferences. If the previous value of `bool _switchValue` is true then it will be set to false and vice versa by using the condition `_switchValue = !_switchValue` and then same will be reflected into the sharedPreferences.

In order to use these values you need to import package "Provider" https://pub.dev/packages/provider refer documentation.

Wrap your material app with the provider.
and create a `ChangeNotifier` and assign child as a `materialApp`.
and create parameter `create : (context) => SwitchHelper()`

like this. and you can access method in your `GestureDetector` or `onTap` method whichever. as : `Provider.of<SwitchHelper>(context).updateValue();`

This will work I think.

Edit :
Your main Method:

```
    void main(){
    runApp(MyApp());}
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
    providers: 
[ 
ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context)=> SwitchHelper())]
child: MaterialApp()...
```

Suppose if you are want to change the switch on click of button.

```
ElevatedButton(
child: Text("click to switch"),
onPressed: (){
Provider.of<SwitchHelper>(context).updateValue();
}
),
```

This way you can call that provider line which will access the function and update the ui without using setState().

Comment: Now I have your code inside of the code which I showed above and also i wrapped my material app like this: return ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => SwitchHelper(),
              child: MaterialApp( ......    now i got an error message :/C:/Users/Public/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
    return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: I have edited the answer check that. and Have you imported provider package?  and If you are using provider it does not require set state..

Comment: Now I have this error message :  Error: A value of type 'Future<SharedPreferences>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SharedPreferences'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.

Comment: initScreen = `await` prefs.getInt("initScreen");    use await in this line. 'Future is from 'dart:async' its warning shown due to updated packages. just click on suggestions on the Future keyword and import dart:async package.